# set theory and real numbers

Tags: set-theory

I'm not a set theorist just done some casual reading so please keep the answer simple...

ZFC has a countable model M (provided it's consistent). In this model the real numbers R are countable (from the outside), but it also satisfies the least upper bound property LUB. Now there's a fast proof that any countable totally ordered set cant have the LUB property (see e.g. Jech's "set theory 3rd millenium edition" chapter 4). On the outside R (in the countable model of ZFC) is countable, so it must have a bounded subset with no least upper bound, meaning the real numbers are disconnected, going against everything we've been taught in analysis. Of course in M it's not disconnected.

My question is: are the open sets that disconnect R not in M? If so this is very crazy since we all have the intuitive notion that the real line is a "continuum" and has no holes in it, yet it does have holes after all but we can't "see" these holes. I'm just a bit confused tbh lol.

Comment: Yeah. And ? What is your point ? Everything you say is correct. And yes, its super weird.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm it... This & Skolem's paradox really makes me go crazy.

Comment: I think a similar example is that if $M$ contains non-standard integers (i.e., not equal to any integers in the real world), then the version of the natural numbers that $M$ has has an initial segment consisting precisely of the standard integers. Clearly, this initial segment is not a set as far as $M$ is concerned, because otherwise that would contradict the principle of induction. $M$ thinks its natural numbers are well-ordered, but they really aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "open sets" that disconnect $\mathbb{R}$ are not in $M$.  In general, in the question you are moving too much between an "inside" and "outside" viewpoint. The meaning of theorems in ZFC is that they hold *inside* any model of ZFC. There is no reason to think they will hold if we consider additional sets that are not in the model.